# Fetch gives cross origin request blocked

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express

I am using node, express and react to create a signin portal. I created an app.js file and signin.js file for the frontend. The signin.js contains the following lines(not the whole code):

```
onSubmitSignIn = () => {
fetch("http://localhost:3001/signin", {
  method : 'post',
  headers : {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
  body : JSON.stringify({
    email : this.state.signInEmail,
    password : this.state.signInPassword
    })
  })
.then(res => res.json())
.then(data => {
  if (data === "Success!!"){
    console.log(data);
   }
 })
this.props.onRouteChange("home");
}
```

The above code prints Success!! in the console.. The onRouteChange passes the home value to a function in app.js which loads the home page.
However when i remove the console.log(data) and put the this.props.onRouteChange("home") in its place, I get the following error:

Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://localhost:3001/signin. (Reason: CORS request did not succeed).

The reason for this interchange is that I can redirect the user to the home page if the user credentials are correct and the express server returns the response "Success!!".
Please help. I have already included the following line in server.js:

```
app.use(cors());
```

I haven't posted the whole code as its too large..

Comment: try adding the following headers to your response at ./signin     <'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': ...,
    'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': ...,
    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'

Comment: "I haven't posted the whole code as its too large" — You need to provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was probably because the form tries to perform a get request by default. I passed the event parameter to onSubmitSignin and added the following line inside it:

```
event.preventDefault();
```

This solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> app.use(cors());
> ```

This is insufficient.

You said:

> ```
> headers : {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
> ```

… so you are triggering a preflight request.

I'm surprised the error message you quoted did not mention preflights. You should test in multiple browsers. Some give better error messages than others.

The documentation for [the cors module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors#enabling-cors-pre-flight) says:

> Enabling CORS Pre-Flight
>
> Certain CORS requests are considered 'complex' and require an initial
>   OPTIONS request (called the "pre-flight request"). An example of a
>   'complex' CORS request is one that uses an HTTP verb other than
>   GET/HEAD/POST (such as DELETE) or that uses custom headers. To enable
>   pre-flighting, you must add a new OPTIONS handler for the route you
>   want to support:
>
> ```
> var express = require('express')
> var cors = require('cors')
> var app = express()
>
> app.options('/products/:id', cors()) // enable pre-flight request for DELETE request
> app.del('/products/:id', cors(), function (req, res, next) {
>   res.json({msg: 'This is CORS-enabled for all origins!'})
> })
>
> app.listen(80, function () {
>   console.log('CORS-enabled web server listening on port 80')
> })
> ```

Comment: When i console log the response,  "Success!!" is printed.. That clearly indicates I'm getting the string as a response. What i fail to understand is that when i try to access the props from inside the if loop it gives me the cors error!